# Ask Homebrew to open URL of a package?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Homebrew packages include a URL to the package webpages. For example:

```
13:38:39 ~ $ brew info atk
atk: stable 2.14.0 (bottled)
http://library.gnome.org/devel/atk/
/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.12.0 (205 files, 3.5M)
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/atk.rb
...
```

Is there a command to get Homebrew to open the URL in a web browser without creating my own?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The command is `brew home <formula>`.